# converting images to dds on linux command line

Tags: linux, command-line, directdraw

I have a bunch of images in jpeg format and i would like to batch convert them to .dds (DirectDraw surface).

Does anyone know a command line tool to achieve such a conversion?

Comment: sorry, not a programming question. Voting to move to superuser.com . Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Nevermind, i already found a solution. I am using the NConvert command line utility and call it via exec() in php.